# QCustomPlot include causes strange errors on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qcustomplot

Whenever I just *include* the file `qcustomplot.h` a huge load of errors come up.
I can't seem to sort this out, especially since it's working all fine on Windows and Mac. Maybe somebody experienced the same problem.

Here are the error messages that come up:

```
In file included from ../maitime/linux_x11.h:9:0,
                 from ../maitime/recognize.h:20,
                 from ../maitime/mainwindow.h:6,
                 from ../maitime/main.cpp:2:
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:64:9: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
         None                    = 0x0000, // obsolete
         ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:64:9: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:64:9: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1102:0,
                 from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:37,
                 from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:37,
                 from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from ../maitime/main.cpp:1:
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:74:41: error: 'PrintDialogOption' was not declared in this scope
     Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(PrintDialogOptions, PrintDialogOption)
                                         ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qflags.h:156:16: note: in definition of macro 'Q_DECLARE_FLAGS'
 typedef QFlags<Enum> Flags;
                ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qflags.h:156:20: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 typedef QFlags<Enum> Flags;
                    ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:74:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DECLARE_FLAGS'
     Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(PrintDialogOptions, PrintDialogOption)
     ^
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/QtPrintSupport:4:0,
                 from ../maitime/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h:54,
                 from ../maitime/mainwindow.h:11,
                 from ../maitime/main.cpp:2:
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:77:44: error: expected ')' before '*' token
     explicit QAbstractPrintDialog(QPrinter *printer, QWidget *parent = 0);
                                            ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:78:28: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
     ~QAbstractPrintDialog();
                            ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:80:22: error: 'virtual' outside class declaration
     virtual int exec() = 0;
                      ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:80:26: error: function 'int exec()' is initialized like a variable
     virtual int exec() = 0;
                          ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:83:27: error: variable or field 'addEnabledOption' declared void
     void addEnabledOption(PrintDialogOption option);
                           ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:83:27: error: 'PrintDialogOption' was not declared in this scope
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:85:41: error: non-member function 'PrintDialogOptions enabledOptions()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     PrintDialogOptions enabledOptions() const;
                                         ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:86:26: error: 'PrintDialogOption' was not declared in this scope
     bool isOptionEnabled(PrintDialogOption option) const;
                          ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:86:52: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'const'
     bool isOptionEnabled(PrintDialogOption option) const;
                                                    ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:90:24: error: variable or field 'setPrintRange' declared void
     void setPrintRange(PrintRange range);
                        ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:90:24: error: 'PrintRange' was not declared in this scope
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:91:5: error: 'PrintRange' does not name a type
     PrintRange printRange() const;
     ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:94:19: error: non-member function 'int minPage()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     int minPage() const;
                   ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:95:19: error: non-member function 'int maxPage()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     int maxPage() const;
                   ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:98:20: error: non-member function 'int fromPage()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     int fromPage() const;
                    ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:99:18: error: non-member function 'int toPage()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     int toPage() const;
                  ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:101:25: error: non-member function 'QPrinter* printer()' cannot have cv-qualifier
     QPrinter *printer() const;
                         ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:103:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'protected'
 protected:
 ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:106:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'private'
 private:
 ^
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:37:0,
                 from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:37,
                 from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
                 from ../maitime/main.cpp:1:
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:1043:35: error: 'QAbstractPrintDialog& operator=(const QAbstractPrintDialog&)' must be a nonstatic member function
     Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
                                   ^
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:107:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_DISABLE_COPY'
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QAbstractPrintDialog)
     ^
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/QtPrintSupport:4:0,
                 from ../maitime/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h:54,
                 from ../maitime/mainwindow.h:11,
                 from ../maitime/main.cpp:2:
../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtPrintSupport/qabstractprintdialog.h:110:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 };
 ^
```

This is my .pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-05-09T21:19:57
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui \
            printsupport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = maiTime
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES +=  main.cpp\
            mainwindow.cpp \
            applicationdata.cpp \
            visualize.cpp \
            windowinfo.cpp \
            record.cpp \
            recognize.cpp \
            restrict.cpp \
            whitelist_dialog.cpp \
            settings.cpp \
            qcustomplot/qcustomplot.cpp


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
            windowinfo.h \
            applicationdata.h \
            visualize.h \
            record.h \
            recognize.h \
            restrict.h \
            whitelist_dialog.h \
            settings.h \
            qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h

macx {
    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += mac.mm
    HEADERS += mac.h
    LIBS += -framework Cocoa
}

unix:!macx {
    HEADERS += linux_x11.h
    SOURCES += linux_x11.cpp
    LIBS += -lX11
    CONFIG += c++11
}

win32 {
    SOURCES += win.cpp
    HEADERS += win.h
    LIBS += -lpsapi
}

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui \
    whitelist_dialog.ui


RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

ICON = lemon.icns
```

When creating an entirely new application, these errors do not come up.
This is by the way how we include the file:
`#include "qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h"`
(Yes, the path is correct)

We are running Qt 5.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things come to my mind. First, according to qcustomplot, the latest released version supports from qt4.6 to qt5.4. Second, could you create a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I will add an MCVE as soon as I am back on my laptop. We did further testing yesterday and it seemed to work alright on a new, clean project but not with all the dependencies we already have. Quite strange since it shouldn't work for 5.5 at all, as you said. Then again, it is working for our Windows and Mac computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help, we found the error.
In fact, it was just a single line that needed re-ordering..
This was our mainwindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "recognize.h"
#include "record.h"
#include "restrict.h"
#include "visualize.h"
#include "whitelist_dialog.h"
#include "qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h"
```

This was our recognize.h:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QString>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "windowinfo.h"
#include "linux_x11.h"
```

This lead to the error. All we had to do was to re-order the include of our recognize.h to the very end, right after

```
#include qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h
```

Thanks for your help!
Always remember, the order of `includes` with qcustomplot under linux matters, a lot!

Also: A link where the *same* problem gets discussed:
http://forum.qtfr.org/discussion/4438/qt4-linux-inclusion-de-xlib-h-qui-pose-probleme (French, unfortunately)